# AFJSONRequestOperation works on simulator but not on device

Tags: objective-c, json, post

I try to get data from the server by POST method.

Here is my code:

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080"]];
httpClient.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"1", @"identity",
                          @"3", @"priority",
                          @"false", @"clearBadge",
                          @"1", @"pushNotificationID",
                          nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *signInRequest = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/.../push/update" parameters:jsonDict];

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

[signInRequest setHTTPBody: jsonData];

[signInRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
signInRequest.timeoutInterval = 15.0;
signInRequest.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;

AFJSONRequestOperation *signInOperation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:signInRequest success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", JSON);
}
                                                                                          failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error userInfo]);
}];

[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:signInOperation];
```

and in simulator i get my data and all works fine.
but when i run it on device, i get this error message:

```
2013-07-17 11:27:43.760 PushApp[11871:907] {
NSErrorFailingURLKey = "http://localhost:8080/.../push/update";
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey = "http://localhost:8080/.../push/update";
NSLocalizedDescription = "Could not connect to the server.";
NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 \"Could not connect to the server.\" UserInfo=0x1e8351b0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:8080/.../push/update, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:8080/.../push/update, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}";}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're connecting to `localhost:8080` so there must be some server running on your 'desktop' machine which is handling these requests. That isn't true on the device (unless you've done something to make it true).

Probably what you want to do is change the bast URL to be the IP address of your 'desktop' machine and ensure that your device is connected to the same network.